# What is the importance of Milkah, Nahor's wife to attribute the children after her?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers

Milka is mentioned a couple of times as giving birth to Nahor's children, e.g.:

> ... וַיֻּגַּד לְאַבְרָהָם לֵאמֹר **הִנֵּה יָלְדָה מִלְכָּה גַם־הִיא בָּנִים** לְנָחוֹר אָחִיךָ׃
>   ... Abraham was told, “Milcah too has borne children to your brother Nahor: ([Gen 22.20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.22.20?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))
>
> וַתֹּאמֶר אֵלָיו בַּת־בְּתוּאֵל אָנֹכִי **בֶּן־מִלְכָּה אֲשֶׁר יָלְדָה לְנָחוֹר**׃
>   She replied, “I am the daughter of **Bethuel the son of Milkah**, whom she bore to Nahor.” ([Gen 24.24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.24.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Rivka stresses her father to be Milka's son and not Nechor's.

So who Milka was and why is she important in the Torah?

Comment: Probably Milkah as opposed to Reumah

Comment: Also, the fact that she was Sarah's sister probably gave her some extra cachet.